# How do I fetch the UID of a page that's been selected with flux:wizard.link?

Tags: typo3, flux, fluid

I'm using the `flux:wizard.link` to select a page from the page tree in Typo3:

```
<flux:field.input name="page_id" label="Select page">
    <flux:wizard.link activeTab="page"/>
</flux:field.input>
```

Now, I want to fetch this page and render it in a container.

```
<v:content.render pageUid="{page_id}" />
```

But the {page_id} has the t3-link saved instead of the expected pageUID (e.g. t3://page?uid=125)
How do I extract the page's UID?

I could let the user enter just the page-id in an input-field, but I'd rather have her select the page via wizard...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to cut the string into two parts:

```
<v:iterator.explode content="{page_id}" glue="uid=" as="newarray">
  {newarray.1}
</v:iterator.explode>
```

The string *page_id* is cut at the phrase '*uid=*' into two parts, which are saved in the array *newarray*. With *{newarray.1}* you can output the second part of the array.

This is most likely not the best solution. It depends on the link which should have always the same structure (containing 'uid=xxx'). But so far it seems to be the only way.